# Approximate the probability

Tags: probability, statistics

A portable radio uses a type of battery that, after installation, has a lifetime with a mean of 8 hours and a standard deviation of $8$ hours. The radio is tested by running it continuously for $30$ days with batteries being replaced immediately after they run down. Approximate the probability that $100$ batteries will run the radio continuously for at least $30$ days.

Does this mean that mean and standard deviation equal to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not for nothing that the guidelines of this site request you to say where the problem is from and show some of your thinking. Partly this is so we can
judge the mathematical level of the most helpful answer.

The shape of the lifetime distribution of batteries is not specified. However, by the Central Limit Theorem (CLT), if you sum 100 independent lifetimes form almost reasonable choice of distribution, you will have a roughly normal distribution. The mean will be $100 \times 8 = 800$ hours.
The variance will be $100 \times 64 = 6400,$ so the SD will be $80$ hours.
There are $24 \times 30 = 720$ hours in 30 days.

If you assume the lifetime $X$ of 100 batteries is normally distributed
with mean 800 and and SD 80 then you seek $P\{X \ge 720\} = P\{Z \ge -1\}$,
where $Z$ is standard normal and you can find the answer in printed normal tables. But by the Empirical Rule (also called '68%-95%-99.7% Rule') and symmetry of the normal distribution, you can draw a sketch and see without tables that the answer has to be close to 84% (68% between $\pm 1$, half of the remaining 32% below $-1$).

If this is for homework, you would need to explain the methods used and assumptions made for getting the mean 800 and SD 80 in terms of formulas in your textbook. Also, to explain the probability equation, and how $-1$ is obtained.

Addendum: What I suppose you are expected to ignore is that lifetime distributions tend to be somewhat or even markedly right-skewed, and that the sum of 100 of them might still be a bit right-skewed rather than exactly normal. Saying that the mean and SD are both 8 hours suggests use of an exponential distribution--even though battery life is not usually well-modeled by an exponential distribution. If this is from a course on reliability, you might be
expected to base your answer on the exact gamma (or Erlang) distribution
that results from summing exponential random variables. In that case, the answer can be computed by software; in R statistical software, '1 - pgamma(720, 100, 1/8)' returns 0.841779, which is in remarkable agreement with the answer using the CLT.

Comment: I got 84.13%. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of good probability ideas in this problem. Hope you absorb them all.

Answer (score 1):

The data you are given says the mean and standard deviation are equal.  It is not possible to have a true normal distribution like this, as a $-2\sigma$ battery would fail $8$ hours before you install it, but I believe you are expected to ignore that.  You are expected to compute the mean and sigma of the sum of $100$ normal variables as described, then see how many standard deviations low you can be and still make $30$ days and convert that to a probability.